# Access OleDB C# Update

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a problem updating an access database.

Code:

```
string CheminSmx = CheminFirm + "\\Cht\\SMX.mdb";
string cmd = "UPDATE XRealMX SET [Montant HT] = @prix WHERE [Code RX] = @bl;";
OleDbConnection CONNEXION_BASE = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + CheminSmx);
using (CONNEXION_BASE)
{
    try
    {
        //On ouvre la cnx à la base
        CONNEXION_BASE.Open();

        //Creation d'un commande (requette) de lecture
        using (OleDbCommand COMMANDE = CONNEXION_BASE.CreateCommand())
        {
            COMMANDE.CommandText = cmd;
            Prix = float.Parse(Prix.ToString().Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            COMMANDE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prix", Prix);
            COMMANDE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bl", numBL);
            COMMANDE.Connection = CONNEXION_BASE;
            COMMANDE.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch { }
    CONNEXION_BASE.Close();
}
```

This code doesn't update my database. I don't know why.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have any exception or error message? What is the value of `Prix` and `numBL` exactly? What is the type of `Montant HT` and `Code RX` columns? And you don't need `COMMANDE.Connection = CONNEXION_BASE;` line since you created your command based on `CreateCommand` method.

Comment: @SonerGönül if he has an exception he cannot see it. Please remove the empty try/catch otherwise the exception is 'swallowed' and you cannot know anything about your problem. (At least print out the exception message - `catch(Exception ex) Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)`

Comment: Remove the ; from the string cmd

Comment: Semicolon is allowed to be there. It's not a problem. @Moussawi do what Steve said and paste here exception message

Comment: I haven't exception message but is it correct ?

Comment: Thank you i have found my error. My parameters was wrong.

Comment: Then I suggest to post an answer detailing what has gone wrong and how do you fixed it. In this way the question will be useful for future readers. Otherwise please delete it.

Comment: Have to agree with Steve. Came to this question get some answers, but this was waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

My code is right. It's worked. But the variable "CheminFirm" hasn't right value.

The data into my database isn't good so I have checked the value and after it's worked.